# div aspect ratio resizing with position:fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a div placed on the bottom-left corner of the browser window by using `position: fixed`. When the user resizes the window, I want the div to resize as well, but preserve the original aspect ratio.

CSS solutions only (or a confirmation that it cannot be done solely using CSS). I'm working in IE9+. I will accept any solution: div resizing by its width OR height.

There were many questions (with solutions) like mine, however none of them seem to provide a solution for when the div is using `position: fixed`. Their solutions must have `position: absolute`, or they don't work.

EDIT 1: Codepen [live example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AEdiy).

EDIT 2: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/1266461) is how I want it to work, whilst still using `position: fixed`.

Comment: can u post a quick fiddle? or codepen actually.. jsfiddle still down

Comment: @webkit indeed it is... anyway, I've added the codepen now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me if you know the aspect ratio in advance -- if so, you can just use a variation of

```
#content:before {
content:'';
float:left;display:block;
width:0;
padding-top:80%; /*height= 80% of width */
}
```

possibly combined with a `min-height` for `#container`? (This is a streamlined variant of [the accepted answer in your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/505649).)

Comment: I've added the code to the codepen example but unfortunately it doesn't work :/ The rectangle is still resizing on both axes.

Comment: @Howie: well, if it changed in width and not in height, it would by definition not be keeping its (width-to-height) aspect ratio.

Comment: Ah yes! I've just missed something in my code, now it's working fine. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Howie Can you let everyone know what has worked for you because there is still no exact answer.

Comment: Sure. The problem was with my setting the height. When I've removed the height property it worked nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are looking for something where you will have a small `div` at the bottom right corner of your window and resizing the browser window will resize the small box.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fixed-box">
    Something...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixed-box {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: does not preserve the aspect ratio

Comment: Ok. But what exactly are you looking to do. Because the link you shared answers your question relating to maintaing aspect ratio.

Comment: it does not when I replace the solution's `position: absolute` with `fixed`. It displays the div in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Ok. The reason could be when you are using `position:absolute` it is positioning relative to its parent which is `position:relative` but when you use `position:fixed` it is positioning relative to the window. The fact that it works with `position:absolute` is because it's parent takes the `padding-bottom: 75%` correctly.